# Spock and Grails: Why gone wrong?

Tags: grails, spock

this is my integration test in Grails 2.5.1: Inside the setup() there is:

```
Role roleAdmin = new Role(RoleType.ROLE_ADMIN.name(), 1000).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
Role roleMerchant = new Role(RoleType.ROLE_MERCHANT.name(), 1).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
Role roleProvider = new Role(RoleType.ROLE_PROVIDER.name(), 2).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
Role roleUser = new Role(RoleType.ROLE_USER.name(), 3).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

RoleGroup roleGroupAdmin = new RoleGroup(RoleGroupType.ADMIN.name()).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
RoleGroup roleGroupCustomer = new RoleGroup(RoleGroupType.CUSTOMERS.name()).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
RoleGroup roleGroupUsers = new RoleGroup(RoleGroupType.USERS.name()).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

RoleGroupRole.create(roleGroupAdmin, roleAdmin, true)
RoleGroupRole.create(roleGroupCustomer, roleMerchant, true)
RoleGroupRole.create(roleGroupCustomer, roleProvider, true)
RoleGroupRole.create(roleGroupUsers, roleUser, true)
```

When run I have this error:

```
| Error 2015-12-21 11:14:04,994 [main] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pi_test`.`role_group_role`, CONSTRAINT `FK_dxc3snhixkg9qn3c46p6hyjli` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`))
```

The classes `User`, `Role` and `RoleGroupRole` are standard classes generated by s2-quickstart from `Spring Security Plugin`.

Why this happens? I flush every insert, but seems that cannot find the id of roles and `RoleGroupRole`.

Thanks for all!

Luis

Comment: The provided error isn't sufficient, please note that unless database is cleared upon each test,one must first try and read\load each object prior to saving it to the DB.

Comment: Right! In fact my Datasource.groovy had the dbCreate = "create-drop", to avoid reading dirty data. (Test db)